# How to reduce pdf file to convert in special character after reading in asp.net c#.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Here is my Code method which is m using to read my pdf files from folder. but when i run my code the files are read and it convert the content of pdf file into special character. How could I reduce it to convert in special character.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\\Rida\","*.pdf"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    lblPdfContent.Text = contents.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File.ReadAllText reads a text file and not a PDF file ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx ).

Comment: You should use a third party component like iTextSharp or PDFSharp

Comment: i m using iTextSharp but still not working.. And give me Special characters in output.

Comment: Raise another question for that issue